# I have just upgraded to IKVM version to 8.6.2 and start getting the error as could not find IKVM.HOME while creating a CIPHER instance

Tags: nuget, window, ikvm

Below is the sample code and

```
 string myKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DigiIntegrationKey"];
            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myKey);
            byte[] IV = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
           ** Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);**
```

Highlighted last line is giving error.

Tried putting IKVM_HOME variable in environment variable but no luck. Also tried using ikvm.properties file but not sure how to use the same